# Why List#add(i, element) method does not replace existing element in Arraylist?

Tags: java

Why Null value is not replaced by "M" in Arraylist?

```
ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
al.add("A");
al.add(10);
al.add("A");
al.add(null);
System.out.println(al);
al.remove(2);
System.out.println(al);
System.out.println(al.get(2));
al.add(2,"M"); // here
System.out.println(al); 
al.add("N");
```

OUTPUT>>>

[A, 10, A, null]

[A, 10, null]

null

[A, 10, M, null]

Comment: `List#add` doesn't replace, it inserts. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-int-E-

Comment: You need to remove and then add. Add itself doesn't replace anything.

Comment: public void add(int index,
       E element)
Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

Comment: Please don't use **raw-types**. If you really want a `List` where you can insert everything (which you should almost never want), at least use `List<Object>` instead of the raw type `List` only.

Comment: Despite the fact that you've been pointed to the right answer could you please give a more specified piece of code in future? The problem is in single line (List#add(2, "M") method execution) but you gave the whole snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are adding “M” on second position in array, so null moves into next place. 
If you want to replace null use al.set

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html